# internet explorer -> Tools -> proxy settings: How to add menu item, create window when clicked, n perform opreations on registry

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, menuitem

I want to add menu item to Internet Explorer-> tools.

For example: 
Exactly like Intrnet explorer-> Tools -> Delete browsing history

I want to add proxy related actions 
For example:
tools -> Enable proxy
tools -> Disable proxy

Also to have proxy cache, i would like to display window exactly like what is displayed when we click on 'Delete browig history'. 
When clicked on internet ex. -> tools -> 'Edit proxy settings' menu item, it will display an additional window. From there user will be displayed cached data for proxy and user will be able to modify proxy data.

I would like to know how i can do this? (which technology can help me in doing this ?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't help to be able to toggle proxy use on and off. Changes in the proxy require a restart of IE anyway.

Besides, is clicking Tools->Internet Options, clicking the Connections tab, clicking the Lan settings button, checking/unchecking the Use Proxy checkbox, and clicking OK really that complicated? I count five mouse clicks; doing it from a new menu item on the Tools menu would only save three clicks of the mouse.

EDIT: Sorry, it takes *six* clicks, not five (only counted one for Tools->Internet Options), so a new item would save a whole 4 clicks of the left mouse button.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of Having it as i.e. -> Tools -> Menu Item i can direct have it as New Icon Next to Tools. I had seen somewhere this. Clicking on Icon was enabling/disabling proxy.(this was done without restarting internet explorer). In advance to this, i would like to allow user to enter data for multiple proxy & select any proxy from this place.
Can you please help me identifying technology & direction in which i should proceed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it @ this place: 
http: //msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753591(VS.85).aspx